How to turn on and off identity insert when using the Import Table function in SSMS
I have two databases on the same SQL Server. One is used for production (used by the users), and the other is a test database used for testing. The testing database has the same tables and structure as those in the production database and most tables have a primary key.
Until recently, this client was using an extremely old SQL Server with SQL Server Enterprise Manager. Copying data from the production database to the test database was easy and straightforward using the Data Transformation feature of SQL Server Enterprise Manager.
Now the client has moved all databases to a new SQL Server and installed SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to maintain the databases. My problem is when I try to copy data in a table from the production database with the Import Data feature in SSMS, it fails saying it cannot copy the data into the primary field on the destination data source.
I've tried using SELECT and INSERT INTO statements in a SSMS query with SET INSERT_IDENTITY ON for the destination table as the first statement of the query and OFF as the last statement of the query.
But when I run this query, I get an error message saying that when using INSERT_IDENTITY in the query, I must supply the list of columns to be imported. Most of the tables have have too many columns to make this feasible.
How can I use SSMS to import tables when the majority, if not all tables, contain a primary key?
This a feature that will be used a lot, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Enterprise Manager implies SQL Server 2000 or older, which is indeed quite old and not supported: it hasn't even had security patches in many years. This is a BIG DEAL, so it's good to see they're finally moving forward... but maybe let them know how serious this is, and incurring some extra labor costs from you because of hiccups like this with unsupported software is a good way to help drive home the message.

If there are no development activities going on in the DEV version, could you restore a backup of production as the new DEV version? Manually trying to sync prod and dev seems like a fools errand.

Do you know if the servers are linked? Do all of the target columns exist at the source?

"Most of the tables have have too many columns to make this feasible."  <-- not true.  with SSMS, you can drag/drop the columns folder into the query and it will insert all columns. see  https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/06/sql-server-tricks-to-replace-select-with-column-names-sql-in-sixty-seconds-017-video/

Thanks, MLeblanc, that sounds very interesting. I'll look into it.

Thanks for everyone's comments. But I found the solution.
In SSMS, right click on the destination database and select "Tasks" -> "Import Data".
Provide the data source and server and enter the credentials to access the source database, then click "Next". Repeat the previous steps for the destination database. Click "Next" and select "Copy data from one or more tables or views" and click "Next".
In the Source Tables and Views list, select the table(s) you want to import, and then (VERY IMPORTANT and what I was missing before) click "Edit Mappings". Select either "Delete rows in the destination table" or "Append rows to the destination table" AND (again very important) if your destination table has one or more primary keys, check "Enable Identity Insert". Click OK and follow the rest of the prompts to finish and import the rows from the source table.
Larry
